# Select same column with different alias and different conditions

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

So I have a employees work schedule and I want to select employee id by day name for reporting in Crystal Report Visual Studio 2012 C#.

**Database**

```
  Employee_ID  |   DayName   | WorkStart 
    EM0001     |   Monday    |  Morning  
    EM0002     |   Monday    |  Morning  
    EM0003     |   Monday    |  Noon     
    EM0004     |   Monday    |  Noon     
    EM0003     |   Thursday  |  Morning  
    EM0004     |   Thursday  |  Morning  
    EM0001     |   Thursday  |  Noon     
    EM0002     |   Thursday  |  Noon
```

And I've tried

```
SELECT Employee_ID as EmMonday FROM table WHERE dayName = 'Monday'
UNION
SELECT Employee_ID as EmThursday FROM table WHERE dayName = 'Thursday';
```

but its just showing EmMonday, and how EmThursday is showing too?

Like this one below

```
 EmMonday | EmThursday 
  EM0001  |   EM0003   
  EM0002  |   EM0004   
  EM0003  |   EM0001   
  EM0004  |   EM0002
```

Comment: Will you be able to provide how your final result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR MYSQL**

```
SET @rank1=0;
SET @rank2=0;

select t1.Employee_ID as EmMonday, t2.Employee_ID as EmThursday from 
(SELECT @rank1 := @rank1+1  as id, Employee_ID FROM T WHERE dayName = 'Monday' ) as t2
left join 
(SELECT @rank2 := @rank2+1  as id, Employee_ID FROM T WHERE dayName = 'Thursday') t1 on t1.id = t2.id
```

[Demo is here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9b766/5/2)

**FOR MSSQL:**

```
select t1.Employee_ID as EmMonday, t2.Employee_ID as EmThursday from 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Employee_ID) as id, Employee_ID FROM T WHERE dayName = 'Monday' ) as t1
left join 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Employee_ID) as id, Employee_ID FROM T WHERE dayName = 'Thursday') t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

`rank` and `RowNumber()` areused here to indicate number of the row over which we will join Mondays and Thursdays.

`T` is your table name.

Comment: it works! but its just showing monday and thurday. and how about monday-sunday? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one query:

```
SELECT Employee_ID as EmMonday, Employee_ID as EmThursday 
FROM table 
WHERE dayName = 'Monday' or dayName = 'Thursday'
```

Comment: OP wants all Mondays to appear only in the 1st column and Thursdays only in 2nd. Your answer will simply produce list of all Mon and Thu duplicated in 2 columns.

Comment: almost, EmMonday showing EmThursday too. Have you tried the code?